# How to save the outcomes of a Loop (with if statement) in R?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, for-loop, save

Is it possible to save the outcome of a loop in a vector? My goal is to have a vector (or list) with the dates (of the vector"gifts") that are smaller than one specific date (date_3 in the code).

```
for (i in 1:21) {
if ((!is.na(gifts[i])) & (gifts[i] < Date_3)) {
  print(gifts[i])
}
}
```

"Gifts" represents a vector that contains a number of dates. 
Date_3 is a specific date

Can anyone help? 
Thanks

Comment: You don't need a for loop. `na.omit(gifts[gifts < Date_3])` should suffice. or `gifts[which(gifts < Date_3)]`

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect! ;)

Answer (score 1):

A for loop is an extremely inefficient way to do this. As pointed out by Psidom on the comments you can accomplish what you want with:

```
na.omit(gifts[gifts < Date_3])
```

A simple comparison using microbenchmark:

```
gifts = seq(as.Date("1910/1/1"), as.Date("1930/1/1"), "years")
Date_3 = as.Date("1921-01-01")

microbenchmark({
    a = vector()
    for (i in gifts) {
        if ((!is.na(gifts[i])) & (gifts[i] < Date_3)) {
            a = c(a, gifts[i])
        }
    }
})
```

Results in:

```
Unit: milliseconds
  min       lq     mean   median       uq     max      neval
 1.306957 1.329337 1.400435 1.350478 1.378751 2.45866   100
```

And using what Psidom suggested:

```
 microbenchmark(
     na.omit(gifts[gifts < Date_3])
)
Unit: microseconds
min      lq     mean median     uq   max     neval
14.674 15.6745 16.99335 16.026 16.512 67.95   100
```

Comparing the mean times the second approach is about 82 times faster. Append to vectors inside a for loop is usually a bad idea and you should always think carefully if you really need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to do store results in a vector of dynamic length, I usually store it in the vector this way:

```
results <- vector()    
for (i in 1:21) {
    if ((!is.na(gifts[i])) & (gifts[i] < Date_3)) {
        results[length(results)+1] <- gifts[i]
    }
}
```

Note that this is what I would use if reading through dynamic data, like digging through files for certain data, where I would fill the vector with `tmp` variables. Psidom is correct that the most efficient way in this case is `na.omit(gifts[gifts < Date_3])`.